# Question on mnemonic device for characters such as 恋, 変, and 湾

Tags: kanji, etymology

I am currently studying kanji by using a number of sites, some of which provide mnemonics to aid in learning. While not a specific radical per se (I think), the top portions of the following characters, 恋, 変, and 湾 are often thought of as a simplification of the character for red: 赤. Thus there are mnemonics provided for kanji like those mentioned that use this idea of "red."

However, http://www.kanjinetworks.com states that the etymology of this (quasi-)radical is as follows:

> 䜌 (Type 1 Phonetic) is 絲 (糸 thread doubled, a character now subsumed in 糸) + 言 words (in its original sense of making verbal distinctions → distinguish) → make tangled threads distinct by stretching and untangling them.

In other words, rather than "red,"  it is in fact a simplification of an archaic character related to the "thread" radical, 糸.

I am interested to know if this is correct, and how native Japanese perceive or conceptualize this (quasi-)radical--as being related to 糸, 赤 or something altogether different.

For example, here is the whole entry from the site on the kanji 変 :

> 変 (9)       ヘン      か（える・わる）        Formerly 變
>
> As per 䜌 (Type 5 Phonetic) as described in 恋 (tangled) + 攵 action indicator → an attempt to untangle a volatile situation, that leads to change → unusual; unusual/wondrous event; political event; internal disturbance.

Comment: See also http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%A6

Comment: @snailplane, thanks. lol @ water from armpits

Answer (score 7):

I'm just a student of Japanese, and I only know how I conceptualize it, not how anyone else does.  So this may not be a very good answer, but I'm typing it anyway in case it's useful.

As I understand it, there are two different 亦:

1. The original 亦
2. 䜌 written as 亦

So, 亦 does not "come from" 䜌, but 䜌 as an element is sometimes written as 亦.  Broadly, then, you can put characters containing 亦 into two categories, which tend to have different sounds.  The large majority appear to be 亦-as-䜌, while 亦-as-亦 shows up in 跡 and 亦 itself, which is used to write one sense of the word また.  So:

When I write 亦-as-亦, I think また.

When I write 亦-as-䜌, I think レン.

Why レン?  Well, it seems to represent that sound:

- 攣{れん} (as in the word 痙攣{けいれん})
- 恋{れん}/ [戀]{れん}

I then draw mental arrows out from レン to what appear to be related readings:

- ヘン, as in 変{へん}/[變]{へん}
- ワン, as in 弯{わん}/[彎]{わん}
- バン, as in 蛮{ばん}/[蠻]{ばん}

I know that's not an answer to your question, but I hope it's helpful anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Probably too detailed for a mnemonic device, but here's an explanation of the characters. In「恋」,「変」, and「湾」, the top (right) was indeed originally「䜌」, and functions as a phonetic component. Their [Old Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese) reconstructions as given by [Zhengzhang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhengzhang_Shangfang) are:

- 戀 /*b·rons/ > Middle Chinese /liuᴇn<sup>H</sup>/ > *On'yomi* れん
- 變 /*prons/ > Middle Chinese /pˠiᴇn<sup>H</sup>/ > *On'yomi* へん
- 灣 /*qroːn/ > Middle Chinese /ʔˠuan/ > *On'yomi* わん
- 䜌 /*b·roːn/, /*b·ron/, /*b·rons/

The top (right) component mentioned is different in origins from:

- 「亦」, originally a person「大」with marks located at and emphasising the armpits;

  ## <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
  [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
  [image]

  [合集32035](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=32035&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>現代
  [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
  [image]</kbd>
- The bottom of「赤」, originally a person「大」and fire「灬」(variant of「火」).

  ## <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]

  [合集15679](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=15679&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
  [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
  [image]
  邾公華鐘
  [集成245](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=245&jgwfl=)</kbd>
  <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
  [image]
  [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
  　<kbd>現代
  楷
  [image]</kbd>

---

The explanation of「攵」in「變」is largely correct.「攵」(variant of「攴」) depicts a hand holding a hitting implement, and in「變」it just represents *motion* in general, leading on to the meaning *change*. 「䜌」, however, just provides a sound hint.

> ## <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [上博2426.31](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=13&bh=2426.31&jgwfl=)
> 合集27742</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)
> 金
> [image]
> 燕侯載器「教」
> [集成10583](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10583&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
> [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
> [image]
> [{{kr: 包}}2.99](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/reference/chuwenziReference)「教」</kbd>
> 　<kbd>現代
> 楷
> [image]
> 「教」</kbd>
>
> Shape evolution of the「攵」component, as shown in later forms in the character「教」.「攵」is found in many characters to do with *attacking/punishing*; the character「教」depicts a child「子」learning arithmetic (represented by two「㐅」, original character of「五」) under threat of being beaten by「攵」. The two「㐅」and「子」later fused into「孝」. Another example is「牧」, which depicts a cow「牛」being herded by a hand with a whip「攵」.

「亦」was chosen to replace「䜌」in simplification efforts because a calligraphic cursive variant of「䜌」looked very similar to「亦」. The similarity can be seen if we look at the following two-step process. First, write the second stroke of「言」long enough to cover「絲」:

## <kbd>[元](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_dynasty)ㆍ[趙孟頫](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhao_Mengfu)
楷
[image]
續千字文「變」</kbd>

Then, abbreviate「絲」and the last five strokes of「言」:

## <kbd>[明](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_dynasty)ㆍ[文徵明](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wen_Zhengming)
[行](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-cursive_script)
[image]
赤壁賦「變」</kbd>

The top now heavily resembles「亦」.