# Differents ways to write 箸

Tags: kanji, homophonic-kanji, kanji-choice

I realized when looking for the kanji for chopsticks that you can actually find 2 versions of the 箸 kanji (see for example [箸 (Jisho)](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%AE%B8%20%23kanji) or [箸 (Jitenon)](http://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjie/2087.html)). Namely, there is sometimes a little stroke above the 日 part of the kanji. Whether or not this stroke is present seems to depend on the font used, maybe it is just a mistake implemented in some fonts.

Does anyone has information about that? Is there a right and a wrong way to write this kanji?

Comment: Related (or duplicate?): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42953/9831

Comment: It's the eleventh character in the fifth row of this chart: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41985/7810

Answer (score 2):

> I realized when looking for the kanji for chopsticks that you can
>   actually find 2 versions of the 箸 kanji   Is there a right and a wrong
>   way to write this kanji?

It says there are at least two variations. The one with the dot in the middle is the normal one, but it's also accepted without the dot as 異体字. (ref: [漢字辞典オンライン | 箸](http://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjie/2087.html))

[image]　[image]

Answer (score 0):

## 日本語

質問者の提供した質問は「正字体」と「異体字」に関するものである。
同じ意味を表す漢字（厳密には漢字以外にひらがな、カタカナ、英数字、記号も含むので「文字」とすべきであるが、便宜的にこの回答では「漢字」という）の「字体」が異なること、すなわち、本来同じ文字として分類すべき異なる「字体」に関する質問である。

なお、「字体」とは[ここ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AD%97%E4%BD%93)では、「図形を一定の文字体系の一字と視覚的に認識する概念、すなわち文字の骨格となる「抽象的な」概念のことである。」とある。素人にはわかりずらく、丁寧に説明するほど説明がむずかしくなり、また不要な意見が噴出しそうなので省略する。

同じ意味を表す漢字が何種類も存在するのは特に情報交換において不自由である。
情報交換では、実際の字体ではなく、該当する漢字に対するコードを交換し、双方で変換テーブルに従ってエンコード、デコードして字体を再現する。
これは、データ量を減らすのが主たる目的である。

この変換テーブルとして、日本で基本となるのが、日本工業規格で定めたものである。

使用される漢字の頻度に応じて、ＪＩＳ第１水準漢字、第２水準漢字のように定められている。
ＪＩＳ第２水準漢字で約６０００数百文字が対象になっている。

歴史的にみると、漢字の活字が開発されるまでは、文字の記録は手書きである。公文書である戸籍も手書きであった。このために、本来同じ字体であるべき文字ですら、届け出者の記憶違い、書き間違い、また、役所での受付者の転記間違いを含めて、字体の異なるいわゆる「異体字」が新たに生じ、結果として多数存在することになった。たとえ転記間違い、記載間違い等であっても、一旦正式書類として受け付けられ登録されると、本来の字体と異なっていても認めざるを得ない。主にこのような歴史的背景から、人名に関する異体字が多数存在することとなった。「渡辺」の旧字体である「渡邊」の「邊」には異体字が数十文字あるというのも有名である。

このような異体字に対してもすべてコードを割り当てる作業が絶えずなされており、第３水準漢字、第４水準漢字と次々と規格（コード表）が作られている。膨大な調査と丁寧な作業とで支えられている規格である。

漢字を使う中国や台湾、日本等を含む漢字圏での国境を越えた情報交換を意図した「国際符号化文字集合」の作業はもっと厄介である。漢字を使う中国や台湾、日本等を含む漢字圏の国では、作業開始の時点で個々の国の「正字体」が相互に微妙に違う上に、日本同様にそれらの国個々の事情に応じて異体字が発生するので、本来同じ意味の漢字に対して異なる字体が一国内で考える以上に多数存在し、すべての字体にコードを割り当てることの困難さが生じている。具体的には特に中国において、アルファベットなどに比べて書く速度が極端に遅くなる漢字の弊害を回避する目的で、文字の部首の簡略化を含めて新しい字体を国策として作ったことは広く知られている。更に必要に応じてこの簡略化手法を利用した異体字が意図的に絶えず作られている。中国において異体字が意図的に作られ、加えられる代表的な例が、人名や地名である。本来昔からの「正字体」で個々に運用されていた画数の多い漢字が、何らかの理由で情報交換の場に登場するようになると、その漢字の表記の効率を上げるために、新たな簡略化された字体を生み出す。これが、最初の「正字体」に対して異体字となる。端的には、無名（有名でないという意味）の土地に大災害が発生したり、無名の人が政府の要人になると、「異体字」が生まれることになる。

## English

I am asking for an English translation. Thank you in advance.

Roughly, as for the two *kanji*s, one is an orthographic character and the other is its variant.
In order to encode Kanjis to realize interoperability in the information and  communication era, this kind of problem has occurred when only one kanji out of ones with the same meaning was assigned as the orthographic character correspending to the specific code and the others were left.

The main reason for the occurrence of variant characters was that the handwritten kanji characters were accepted at the government office and formally registered. A typical example is "family register 戸籍｛こせき｝", that is why the variant characters are the most popular in person names, though 箸 is not applied to this case.